# How can I get the rel value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, rel

I use jQuery UI drag&drop functions to select images an album. The images ID straged in the rel parameter, what I need to copy to an input element after image drop.

Here is the image list. Using draggable

```
<img src="01.jpg" title="image 01" rel="10" />
<img src="02.jpg" title="image 02" rel="11" />
<img src="03.jpg" title="image 03" rel="12" />
```

Drop here:

```
<div id="dropzone">
    <div id="imgcontainer"></div>
    <input type="text" name="img_id" id="img_id" />
</div>
```

The droppable JS code is here:

```
$('#dropzone').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'bgSelected',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).html(''); // to remove any other stuffs
        var img = ui.draggable;
        $('<img src="'+img.prop('src')+'" title="'+img.prop('title')+'">').appendTo( $(this) );
        $('<input type="text" name="img_id" id="img_id" value="'+img.prop('rel')+'" />').appendTo( $(this) );
    },
});
```

And the img.prop('rel') return with empty string. I tried to use img.attr('rel'), but that return an object element. How can I get the "rel" value?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `attr` insted of prop.
like ..

```
$(function() {
  $('#dropzone').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'bgSelected',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
         var img = ui.draggable;
        //alert($(ui.draggable));
        var id =img.attr('rel');


    $(this).html(''); // to remove any other stuffs

     $('<img src="'+img.prop('src')+'" title="'+img.prop('title')+'">').appendTo( $(this) );
      $('<input type="text" name="img_id" id="img_id" value="'+id+'" />').appendTo( $(this) );
    },
  });
```

this is a fiddle  link http://jsfiddle.net/fLJuB/19/

Comment: img.attr('rel') is returning an object element. The alert say: [object Object]

Comment: it means your `ui.draggable;` return some other obj can you show me fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#img").attr("rel"));
```

if you use .attr("rel").**text()** it won't work.

Comment: img.attr('rel') is returning an object element. The alert say: [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some jquery selector if you get other properties in the object with ui.draggable. For example, if `img.prop('src')` returns src attribute right, you can use it to  select the image with jquery attribute selector

```
alert($('img[src="' + img.prop('src') + '"]').attr('rel'));
```

EDITED: Hi think this works fine -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fLJuB/4/)

Comment: hm... thats cool, but what was wrong? You use img.attr('rel') , like me :)

Comment: mmmm....I don't know....may be you updated the code, but didn't refresh...who knows :)